# Send JSON data from Ember to Spring

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I try to send JSON data from my Ember application to Spring REST application, but in spring console i see:

```
json = %7B%22username%22%3A%22userTest%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22passwordTest%22%7D=
```

What is wrong with this POST request?

```js
create() {
    var _this = this;
    var userData = {
        "username": "userTest",
        "password": "passwordTest"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/createUser',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(userData),
    })
}
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestBody String user) {
    System.out.println("json = " + user);
}
```

Comment: FYI you should never use `async: false`. It locks the UI thread while the request is processing and looks to the user as though the browser has crashed.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, thank you, but it still doesn't work correctly..